# What's the proper sequence of Airflow commands to run to schedule a DAG?

Tags: airflow

I don't understand what command(s) I need to run in order to get a DAG scheduled. Let's say I tested the DAG using `airflow test dag_name task_id_1 2017-06-22` and the second task with `airflow test dag_name task_id_2 2017-06-22`.

I ran `airflow trigger_dag dag_name`, but is that for instantiating the DAG for just right that moment?

Let's say I want the `dag_name`'s timing/scheduling to look like:

```
'start_date': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 22, 18),
'end_date': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 23, 20),
schedule_interval = datetime.timedelta(1)
```

So I just want to schedule and run it today and tomorrow, starting @ 18:00 UTC today and 24 hours after that.

Now what command or list of commands am I supposed to run? Do I have to run `airflow scheduler` every time I want to add and schedule a DAG?

Answer (score 1):

trigger_dag is to trigger the dag run instantaneously. To schedule the DAG, just put it in the DAG folder, go to Airflow UI and enable the DAG.